# Creating a function to find duplicates in array without sorting C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I've been working on a lottery checking program. The goal is to create a function that finds duplicates and allows the user to choose another number in the case of userTicket, and generate another random number in case of winningNums. So this function must be reusable between the two, or with any array for the matter. I am not familiar with sorting and scanning through the array just yet. I have created a nested for loop to go through each index and compare the two between [i] and [j]. My function only works on the first number for some reason. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

```
void getLottoPicks(int userArray[])
{

    cout << "Please enter your 7 lotto number picks between 1 and 40.\n";


    for (int i = 0; i < NUMS; i++)
    {
            cout << "selection #" << i + 1 << ":";

            cin >> userArray[i];
            cin.ignore();

                if (noDuplicates(userArray) == true)
                {

                    cout << "You already picked this number. Please enter a different number: " << endl;
                    cin >> userArray[i];

                }           
    }

}


void genWinNums(int winArray[])
{
    srand((int)time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMS; i++)
    {
        winArray[i] = rand() % 40 + 1;

        if (noDuplicates(winArray) == true)
        {
            winArray[i] = rand() % 40 + 1;
        }
    }
}

bool noDuplicates(int dupArray[])
{
    int temp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMS; i++)
    {
        //temp += dupArray[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (dupArray[i] == dupArray[j])
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just put them in a Set instead, then check for membership? Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I'm not sure what a set is. I'm trying to pass down my arrays which contain the users chosen lottery numbers and another with the randomly generated winning numbers to check if they have a duplicate.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with "Creating a function to find duplicates in array without sorting".  That's pretty much the only part you have done correctly.  This is about you having the rest of your logic wrong.  I would suggest that you learn how to use a debugger.  If you are overwhelmed by the idea of using a debugger, you can also try rubber-duck debugging, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging. (A rubber duck is definitely not as intimidating as a debugger.)

Comment: @MikeNakis I've gone back and forth through the code, explaining to myself how it works, along with explaining it on paper to have a good visual. I am only a beginner and only ask for advice when I've tried everything  I can think of. From what I understood from your comment is that my function is constructed properly, the functions that are calling the noDuplicates are not. So I am now trying to find different ways of configuring them. If you have any advice towards the code, that'll be great, thanks.

Comment: @FranticCode The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks. I'll be taking a look at that post .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/), it's faster and much less code

```
void getLottoPicks(std::set<int> userArray)
{

    cout << "Please enter your 7 lotto number picks between 1 and 40.\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMS; i++)
    {
        cout << "selection #" << i + 1 << ":";
        int num;
        cin >> num;
        cin.ignore();

        // while the num is already in the set
        while (userArray.find(num) != userArray.end())
        {
            cout << "You already picked this number. Please enter a different number: " << endl;
            cin >> num;
        }           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In both cases your calls to `noDuplicates()` are nested inside the loops which are constructing the array that you pass to `noDuplicates()`.  That won't work.  First you need to construct the array, and once you are done constructing it, *then* you pass it to `noDuplicates()`.

Comment: I understand that. But the user is asked 7 times to make a selection. If any one selection is the same number that exists in the array, it should prompt a message stating "You have already selected this number" . If noDuplicates was called outside of the for loop of which the numbers for the array are being generated, how would the program go back to the index in which there is a duplicate and prompt for example "Selection #3" to be entered again. The code is supposed to be designed in a way where it is actively searching.

Comment: Well then, you have some serious re-organization to do on your code. But you cannot have code that is organized in a way that it won't do what you need to do, and on top of that invoke functions in ways that constitute logical errors.  When a function expects an array of `NUM` elements, and you invoke it with an array in which only the first element has been initialized, it will not work.  There is no "yes, but". It won't work, you need to find another way of doing things.

Comment: exactly what I am currently doing, thanks for the tips!